# My helper methods in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

My app should render html, to answer when a user clicks ajax-link.

My controller:

```
def create_user
  @user = User.new(params)
  if @user.save
    status = 'success'
    link = link_to_profile(@user) #it's my custom helper in Application_Helper.rb
  else
    status = 'error'
    link = nil
  end

  render :json => {:status => status, :link => link}
end
```

My helper:

```
  def link_to_profile(user)
    link = link_to(user.login, {:controller => "users", :action => "profile", :id => user.login}, :class => "profile-link")
    return(image_tag("/images/users/profile.png") + " " + link)
  end
```

I have tried such methods:

```
ApplicationController.helpers.link_to_profile(@user)
# It raises: NoMethodError (undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass)
```

and:

```
class Helper
  include Singleton
  include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
  include ApplicationHelper
end
def help
  Helper.instance    
end

help.link_to_profile(@user)
# It also raises: NoMethodError (undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass)
```

In addition, yes, I KNOW about :helper_method, and it works, but i don't want to overload my ApplicationController with a plenty of that methods

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Oki. Let's recap. You want access to certaint functions/methods, but you don't want those methods to be attached to current object.

So you want to make a proxy object, that will proxy/delegate to those methods.

```
class Helper
  class << self
   #include Singleton - no need to do this, class objects are singletons
   include ApplicationHelper
   include ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper
   include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
   include ApplicationHelper
  end
end
```

And, in controller:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def your_method
    Helper.link_to_profile
  end
end
```

The main disadvantage to this approach is that from the helper functions you won't have access to controller context (EG you won't have access to params, session, etc)

A compromise would be to declare those functions as private in the helper module, therefore, when you will include the module, they will also be private in the controller class.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  private
  def link_to_profile
  end
end

class UserController < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```

, as [Damien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590912/my-helper-methods-in-controller/2590974#2590974) pointed out.

**Update**: The reason why you get the 'url_for' error is that you do not have access to controller's context, as stated above. You could force passing the controller as a parameter(Java-style ;) ) like:

```
Helper.link_to_profile(user, :controller => self)
```

and then, in your helper:

```
def link_to_profile(user, options)
  options[:controller].url_for(...)
end
```

or event a bigger hack, presented [here](http://kpumuk.info/ruby-on-rails/memo-6-using-named-routes-and-url_for-outside-the-controller-in-ruby-on-rails/). However, i would reccomend the solution with making methods private and including them in the controller.

Comment: Yes, i have tried your first method, but i got: NoMethodError (undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass). I think, the helper module can't get access to ActionView's helpers

Comment: Yap, you must have access to the context of the controller.

Comment: I updated my response to take in consideration what you said.

Comment: Wouldn't class << self include the same as replacing include by extend?

Answer (score 15):

helpers are just ruby modules which you can include in any controller just like any module.

```
module UserHelper
    def link_to_profile(user)
        link = link_to(user.login, {:controller => "users", :action => "profile", :id => user.login}, :class => "profile-link")
        return(image_tag("/images/users/profile.png") + " " + link)
    end
end
```

And, in your controller :

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
    include UserHelper

    def create
        redirect_to link_to_profile(User.first)
    end
end
```

Comment: i don't want to include the whole userhelper. And if I would do this, UserController will make that methods available to request them via GET - /users/link_to_profile. I can make custom class, but what should I include, to get method "url_for" ?

Comment: You can't include only one method from a module.
Create a new helper with only the methods you want included in controler.

And include these methods as private so they won't be accessible from http requests.

Answer (score -1):

Take that! http://apotomo.de/2010/04/activehelper-rails-is-no-pain-in-the-ass/

That's exactly what you were looking for, dude.

Comment: Link without explanation is not helpful and not an answer. Use comments for this instead.