# Rails: method defined in application_helper.rb not recognized by categories_controller.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

More newbie issues.

I understand that if I define a method in my application helper, it is available to the entire app code.

In my applicaton helper, I have:

```
def primary_user_is_admin

  if current_user
    user_login_roles = JSON.parse(current_user.role)
    if user_login_roles["admin"]
      return 1
    end
  end
  return nil
end
```

If I call it from the categories_controller:

```
if !primary_user_is_admin
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

I get an error message: undefined local variable or method `primary_user_is_admin'

This also happens if I put the primary_user_is_admin code in the registrations_helper.rb file

However, if I use it in any of the views (views/user/edit.html.erb for instance)

```
<% if primary_user_is_admin %>
<% end >
```

then it works. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["undefined method" when calling helper method from controller in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388932/undefined-method-when-calling-helper-method-from-controller-in-rails)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Helpers are not included into a controller by default. You can

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

To gain access to the methods in the ApplicationHelper module. The [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590912/my-helper-methods-in-controller) has a bunch of useful solutions for accessing helpers in controller.

Comment: any idea on how to include the application helper in an initializer:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23035947/rails-4-use-application-helpers-inside-initializers

Answer (score 4):

Methods defined in helpers are only available to views by default. You have to 'include ApplicationHelper' in the applications controller to get access to this method in the controllers.